# Any workaround for enabling create opportunity splits for users of lower role hierarchy than the record owner?

Tags: opportunity, custom-permission, opportunity-split

Just saw in the ideas that a functionality is not available till now, that a user having lower role hierarchy than that of the opportunity owner, is not having access to the "Edit Opportunity Splits" Button in order to create opportunity splits.

Clearly its a permission that is never granted to the users belonging to the lower level role hierarchies.

But what I need to know is that can't it be achieved even via some sharing settings, as i couldn't locate any object named as Opportunity Splits to have some sharing rules???

Another question...

If i decide to design a vf page that exactly imitates the standard split opportunity functionality of salesforce, can I make it work out of the box to support those users in creating opportunity split records??
Please help.

Comment: I also have a same requirement. Could you please share the solution that  you implemented for this? I posted another question as below for same .https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324530/opportunitysplit-custom-edit-screen-using-lwc